# Gtk.Stack won't change visible child inside an event callback function

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

So I am currently working on an app for elementary os and encountered a problem.
I have a window which has a Granite.Sourcelistview on the left and a stack holding the different views on the right. My problem is that when pressing a button on one of the screens (the project settings screen i created), the stack should change the current view to a different one but it doesn't. The current view stays and is not changed.

This is the window:

```
public class MainWindow : Gtk.Window {

private SourceListStackView srcl_view {get; set;}

construct {

    var header = new Gtk.HeaderBar ();
    header.show_close_button = true;

    //this is the source list view
    srcl_view = new SourceListStackView ();

    var paned = new Gtk.Paned (Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    paned.position = 130;
    paned.pack1 (srcl_view, false, false);
    paned.add2 (srcl_view.stack);

    add(paned);

    set_titlebar (header);
}

public static int main(string[] args) {
    Gtk.init (ref args);

    MainWindow app = new MainWindow ();
    app.show_all ();
    Gtk.main ();
    return 0;
}
}
```

This is the sourcelistview class that i created:

```
    public class SourceListStackView : Granite.Widgets.SourceList {

    public Gtk.Stack stack {get; set;}

public SourceListStackView () {
    var project_page = new ProjectSettings ();
    stack = new Gtk.Stack ();

    var project = new Granite.Widgets.SourceList.ExpandableItem("Root");

    this.root.add(project);

    stack.add_named(project_page, "hello");

    //here depending on what item of the sourcelist is created,
    //the view with the same name as the item 
    //should be displayed (not the best mechanism but works)

    this.item_selected.connect ((item) => {
        if(item != null){
            stack.visible_child_name = item.name;
        }  
    });

    //problematic part is here: This won't change the current view..why? 
    //The button should add another item to the
    // source list view and change the current view
    // to the newly created Welcome Screen but it doesn't do that..
    project_page.button.clicked.connect(() => {
        project.add(new Granite.Widgets.SourceList.Item ("Welcome"));
        stack.add_named(new Granite.Widgets.Welcome("bla bli blu", "bla"), "Welcome");
        stack.set_visible_child_name("Welcome"); 
    });

}
}
```

This is the view with the button that should trigger the change of the view:

```
public class ProjectSettings : Granite.SimpleSettingsPage {
public Gtk.Button button {get; set;}
public ProjectSettings () {
    Object (
        activatable: false,
        description: "This is a screen",
        header: "",
        icon_name: "preferences-system",
        title: "Screen"
    );
}

construct {
    var project_name_label = new Gtk.Label ("Name");
    project_name_label.xalign = 1;

    var project_name_entry = new Gtk.Entry ();
    project_name_entry.hexpand = true;
    project_name_entry.placeholder_text = "Peter";

    content_area.attach (project_name_label, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    content_area.attach (project_name_entry, 1, 0, 1, 1);

    button = new Gtk.Button.with_label ("Save Settings");

    action_area.add (button);
}
}
```

The part that does not work is this one:

```
//problematic part is here: This won't change the current view.. why?
project_page.button.clicked.connect(() => {
    project.add(new Granite.Widgets.SourceList.Item ("Welcome"));
    stack.add_named(new Granite.Widgets.Welcome("bla bli blu", "bla"), "Welcome");
    stack.set_visible_child_name("Welcome");
});
```

I do not know why it wont change the view. I specifically tell it to set the visible child to "Welcome" (and that is exactly how i named it one line above), but it just won't appear. Can someone explain to me why?
I can easily change the stack's visible child outside of the signal/event but inside of it won't do the trick..

Thanks a lot

Update: The issue was solved through José Fonte's comment down below: I instantiated the view, called the **show_all ()** method on it and then added it to the stack and set the visible child to it.

Comment: The term "signal" is already occupied by something in the POSIX world. I'd suggest you replace that with notification or event, since you don't mean POSIX signal. Preferably, use the term used by the framework you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I changed it

Comment: I do not have Granite installed so I can't reproduce the given example. Does `Granite.Widgets.Welcome` get shown after instantiation? If not, and I quote, "Note that the child widget has to be visible itself (see show) in order to become the visible child of this.". Try to instantiate it first, call show on it and then add it to the `Gtk.Stack`. It should work.

Comment: José Fonte, why are you so good at this? It worked, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Glad to help ;) Good luck